# RESTful APIs for unnormalized (NoSQL) entities?

Tags: rest, cassandra, microservices, nosql

I am currently working on a project where we are developing a set of microservices in Scala with Cassandra as our database. I was wondering whether we have any standards
for writing RESTful APIs for entities that are not even in 1st Normal Form ??

I will cite a typical example.

Consider an entity set Fruits. In the traditional RDBMS if we were to store the colors of the fruits we could create a table Colors have
a integer associated with each color as its primary key. For mapping a color to a fruit you could have another relation that would map fruits to colors. Our database
design satisfies Boyce Codd Normal form and we can design intuitive REST end points.

```
/fruits(/:id)
/colors(/:id)
/fruits/:id/colors
/colors/:id/fruits
```

Enter NoSQL databases. Colors is an attribute of the Fruits entity sets itself and it's domain is a set of varchar. If I were to insert Apple into the dataset and associate
colors red and green, I would have to store these strings as a part of that record in a set.

What if I want to update the entity now and remove green from the list ? Or maybe add a new color to the list ?

Should this be broken into a separate endpoint irrespective of the underlying database design ? Or should it be part of the payload ?

Something similar to

```
{
    "name": "Apple",
    "colors": ["green', "red"]
}
```

Thanks,

Utsav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering whether we have any standards for writing RESTful APIs for entities that are not even in 1st Normal Form ??

Yup; the good news is that they are the same standards that apply when entities are in 1st Normal Form:

*REST doesn't care how URI are spelled*

A large part of the point of REST is that clients are insulated from the details of your data storage.

In other words, if you think these spellings make sense to identify resources in your integration domain when you store your data in a RDBMS

```
/fruits(/:id)
/colors(/:id)
/fruits/:id/colors
/colors/:id/fruits
```

Then those spelling should also be satisfactory for an API backed by a NoSQL store.

It's the job of *your implementation* to bridge the gap between the semantic meaning of the resources in your integration domain and your storage.

Here's another spelling of the same idea; from the point of view of the client, all HTTP servers are document stores.  The URI is a key, the representation is the value.  There's an infinite number of keys available, and a small number of verbs (methods) that are expected to be supported for any given key.

It's the job of your API to make your service (whatever it is) look like a dumb HTTP document store.